# Scrapy overwrite json files instead of appending the file

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way to overwrite the said file instead of appending it?

Example)

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o "/path/to/json/my.json" -t json    
scrapy crawl myspider -o "/path/to/json/my.json" -t json
```

Will append the my.json file instead of overwrite it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
scrapy crawl myspider -t json --nolog -o - > "/path/to/json/my.json"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. So the simple "- >" part overwrites the file?

Comment: -o - : redirects to standard output, and > redirects the standard ouput to a new file with following path. I used it and worked weirdly, like i got unvalid json output.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work when I call it using subprocess.check_output, inside a Docker container?

Command '['scrapy', 'crawl', 'spider_name', '-t', 'json', '--nolog', '-o', '-', '>', 'output.json', '-a', 'url=url.jpg]' returned non-zero exit status 2

Comment: See @Samuel Elh answer, upgrade to Scrapy 2.4+ for easy -O overwrite command line option

Answer (score 11):

There is a flag which allows overwriting the output file, you can do so by passing the file reference via `-O` option instead of `-o`, so you can use this instead:

```sh
scrapy crawl myspider -O /path/to/json/my.json
```

More information:

```sh
$ scrapy crawl --help
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

Run a spider

Options
=======
--help, -h              show this help message and exit
-a NAME=VALUE           set spider argument (may be repeated)
--output=FILE, -o FILE  append scraped items to the end of FILE (use - for
                        stdout)
--overwrite-output=FILE, -O FILE
                        dump scraped items into FILE, overwriting any existing
                        file
--output-format=FORMAT, -t FORMAT
                        format to use for dumping items

Global Options
--------------
--logfile=FILE          log file. if omitted stderr will be used
--loglevel=LEVEL, -L LEVEL
                        log level (default: DEBUG)
--nolog                 disable logging completely
--profile=FILE          write python cProfile stats to FILE
--pidfile=FILE          write process ID to FILE
--set=NAME=VALUE, -s NAME=VALUE
                        set/override setting (may be repeated)
--pdb                   enable pdb on failure
```

Comment: That's true, however the `-O` option is very new. Not sure, but I think it was introduced in version 2.4.0, so it is probably not available for everybody yet.

Answer (score 7):

To overcome this problem I created a subclass from `scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FileFeedStorage` in myproject dir.

This is my `customexport.py`:

```
"""Custom Feed Exports extension."""
import os

from scrapy.extensions.feedexport import FileFeedStorage


class CustomFileFeedStorage(FileFeedStorage):
    """
    A File Feed Storage extension that overwrites existing files.

    See: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L79
    """

    def open(self, spider):
        """Return the opened file."""
        dirname = os.path.dirname(self.path)
        if dirname and not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)
        # changed from 'ab' to 'wb' to truncate file when it exists
        return open(self.path, 'wb')
```

Then I added the following to my `settings.py` (see: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.2/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-storages-base):

```
FEED_STORAGES_BASE = {
    '': 'myproject.customexport.CustomFileFeedStorage',
    'file': 'myproject.customexport.CustomFileFeedStorage',
}
```

Now every time I write to a file it gets overwritten because of this.

Comment: nice solution.  Is it a good idea to redefine FEED_STORAGES_BASE in your settings.py? In this case, `scrapy crawl ` commands would still be facing the issue.

Comment: I would call it `OverwriteFileFeedStorage`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old, [well-known "problem"](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/547) of Scrapy. Every time you start a crawl and you do not want to keep the results of previous calls you **have to** delete the file. The idea behind this is that you want to crawl different sites or the same site at different time-frames so you could accidentally lose your already gathered results. Which could be bad.

A solution would be to write an own item pipeline where you open the target file for `'w'` instead of `'a'`.

To see how to write such a pipeline look at the docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline (specifically for JSON exports: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file)

Comment: Can I do something similar with an exporter.py script where I instantiate a custom JsonItemExporter class with my edits? ( I'm still a novice programmer so I don't know if I'm saying it correctly) and then add self.file = open(file, 'wb')? I'm not sure if that's the correct way either

Answer (score 0):

Since, the accepted answer gave me problems with unvalid json, this could work:

```
find "/path/to/json/" -name "my.json" -exec rm {} \; && scrapy crawl myspider -t json -o "/path/to/json/my.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add:

```
import os

if "filename.json" in os.listdir('..'):
        os.remove('../filename.json')
```

at the beginning of your code.

very easy.