# In Scrapy how to check whether exported file already exists?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I write some Scrapy spider. It exported data to file which name I passed via command line: `E:\Anaconda3\envs\Blog2Doc\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py runspider blog2doc_scrapy\spiders\blog_spider.py -o ..\data\out.html`. If this file already exists this spider just append content to the existed file. How to check whether output file already exists and if it exists - delete it. For exporting to file I write Blog2DocExporter(BaseItemExporter) class. It is not opened output file, in constructor it gets already opened file object. So In this exporter class I can't check whether exported file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy overwriting the output files is a known open issue. See for example:

- [output as xml appending to existing file when spider re-executed resulting in invalid xml](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2071)
- [Add a command-line option for overwriting exported file](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/547)

I have myself proposed a fix to rename files with incrementing suffixes. But the implementation is not backward compatible.
You may find this useful nonetheless: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2093

It changes the `FileFeedStorage`, but you could implement something similar and look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823149/) to use such custom feed storage class.